# Repeat on user press, open up terminal, close terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

I am making a program and would like it to loop if an user presses a key. I also want to know if the bash file can automatically open a command terminal if it is not running from one to achieve the above task?

```
#!/usr/sh
bash /random/bash
kill process
#On user press, repeat
#else
kill process
```

And after that, how do I get the bash file to automatically close the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the loop you can use the `while` and `read -n1` waiting for a user presses a key. To close terminal after run script you can use `./script.sh && exit` To open terminal:

```
gnome-terminal -e command
xterm -e command
konsole -e command
terminal -e command
```

Comment: What is the part that you were talking about? (in the script) P.S. I just want for the user to press Enter or something.

Comment: The answer was edited.